# Service freezes when calling XDocument.Root.Add(XElement)

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am working on a service that runs periodic scans on a certain folder to gather information about some of the files that are in it and its subfolders.

I have tested the code in a console application and it runs through as expected, however when it runs from my service, the execution seems to get stuck at the part where it calls scanLog.Root.Add(temp);

I can see the event entry that says "Starting to add node", however it never gets to "Finished adding node" any thoughts on why this doesn't work in my service, but works fine in a console application?

```
private void ScanForChildCopies(string dir)
    {
        foreach(var dirs in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
        {
            ScanForChildCopies(dirs);
        }

        foreach(var files in Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.ac"))
        {
            FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(files);
            serviceLogging.WriteEntry("Found File: " + files);
            if (fInfo.Exists)
            {
                if ((DateTime.Now - fInfo.LastWriteTime).Days > 0)
                {
                    serviceLogging.WriteEntry("Building node");
                    XElement temp = new XElement("childfile", new XElement("name", fInfo.Name), new XElement("lastmodified", fInfo.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString()),
                        new XElement("age", (DateTime.Now - fInfo.LastWriteTime).Days.ToString()));
                    serviceLogging.WriteEntry("Starting to add node");
                    scanLog.Root.Add(temp);
                    serviceLogging.WriteEntry("finished Adding node to scanlog");                 
                }                    
            }
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue that was causing the service to hang.

```
scanLog.Root.Add(temp);
```

scanLog was declared as a static XDocument at the beginning, but was redeclared within the function that was calling the posted function.

Answer (score -1):

One of the reasons why it never executes, might be because you are trying to edit files which are in the same folder as service that you are calling.

Comment: It hangs when trying to add an XElement (temp) to an existing XDocument so no writing to an actual file is occuring at this stage, it should just be building the xml in memory and adding it to the XDocument object.

Comment: When you say service, are you referring to a web service hosted in IIS or a windows service...

Comment: @Umair Farooq I know for a fact that IIS will reset app pool, if you write anything into a mapped folder... I was simply referring that this might be happening in Vladmere case...

Comment: A windows service that was installed to my local machine using InstallUtil for testing purposes.